# Animate font-size of before in span and keep the span text's position

Tags: html, css, transition, font-size

I have a like-button which consists out of a `<span>` with a heart (font icon) as the `:before`. When the `:hover` or `:active` state is active, the `:before`'s font-size increases (with a transition on it).

Now the problem: the span text changes position. **I'd rather have it stay in the same place.**

*normal state:*

[image]

*hover state:*

[image]

*active state (click):*

[image]

HTML:

```
<span class="comment-likes icon-ico-heart">12</span>
```

SASS:

```
.comment-likes
  user-select: none
  color: #92a3b9
  cursor: pointer

  &:before
    +transition(font 100ms linear, color 100ms linear)

  &:hover::before
    font-size: 13px
    color: lighten($main-color, 15%)

  &:active::before
    font-size: 20px
    color: $main-color

  &.active
    color: $main-color

    &:hover::before
      color: $main-color
```

Comment: What icons set do you use?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: the SVG's are converted to a font with icomoon.

Comment: So don't animate font size, use `scale(2)` with a `transform-origin` of `"50% 50%"`

Comment: Nevermind, in that case, you're probably stuck with something like line-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.comment-likes {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: hsl(213, 21%, 72%);
  cursor: pointer;
  font: 11px/1 sans-serif;
}

.comment-likes:before {
  font: normal normal normal 11px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: "\f004";
  margin-right: 4px;
  
  display:inline-block; /* in order to allow CSS3 transform scale */
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.comment-likes:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  color: hsl(213, 51%, 62%);
}

.comment-likes:active:before {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  color: hsl(213, 71%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<span class="comment-likes">12</span>
```